# Can I store a multi-level secrets JSON in AWS Secrets Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

Suppose I wanted to store something like:

```json
{
    "service_name": {
        "prod": "SECRET1",
        "dev": "SECRET2"
    }
}
```

Can I store such JSON in [AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/reference_secret_json_structure.html) - regardless of the JSON structure, to AWS, you will be storing a string ([`SecretString`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_CreateSecret.html#SecretsManager-CreateSecret-request-SecretString)), or binary.

Creating the secret:

```bash
aws secretsmanager create-secret \
    --name TestSecret \
    --description "Test secret" \
    --secret-string "{\"service_name\":{\"prod\":\"SECRET1\",\"dev\":\"SECRET2\"}}"
```

Retrieving the secret:

```bash
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value \
    --secret-id TestSecret \
    --query SecretString \
    --output text
```

Output:

```json
{"service_name":{"prod":"SECRET1","dev":"SECRET2"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on to [Ermiya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77426598/3390419), if you have that json in a file (or variable) you can easily serialize/deserialize it using `jq`. Given:

```bash
$ cat file
{
    "service_name": {
        "prod": "SECRET1",
        "dev": "SECRET2"
    }
}
```

then creating the secret:

```
$ aws secretsmanager create-secret \
    --name TestSecret \
    --description "Test secret" \
    --secret-string "$(jq '. | @json' file)"
```

retrieving the secret:

```bash
$ aws secretsmanager get-secret-value \
    --secret-id TestSecret \
    --query SecretString \
    --output text | jq -r '.'
{"service_name":{"prod":"SECRET1","dev":"SECRET2"}}
```